# Semantics of stability

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, vacuum

In the description of the Higgs vacuum (but also generally in QFT), I've seen the words *stable*, *unstable*, *metastable*, *true* and *false* pop up.

My understanding is as follows. For a **stable** vacuum, I picture the bottom of a positive quadratic potential: small perturbations bring you back to the vacuum.

The possibility of having *several vacuua* instead of just the one bring forth the idea of **true** vacuum: assuming they're not all degenerate, one of them lies the lowest.

In this case, any *locally stable* (i.e. not stable if large perturbations or instanton effects are allowed) with higher energy will be deemed a **false** vacuum, for obvious reasons. These might be long-lived, but not eternal, and will eventually decay to the true vacuum.

---

Now, I would think that an **unstable** vacuum is just that - unstable. Like a ball at the top of a hill (or a negative quadratic potential), the slightest perturbation will send it rolling quickly downhill.

And now I've ran out of cases - where does a **metastable** vacuum fit, then? Is it a false vacuum in a theory that admits only that vacuum and "minus infinity" as minima? (i.e. it could tunnel not to a true, stable vacuum but just get negative infinite energy).

---

**tl;dr** : what are the proper definitions of *unstable* and *metastable* vacua?

Comment: I believe that metastable and false vacuums are essentially synonymous. I would guess that the reason for the 2 terminologies is that the term "false vacuum" originated in particle physics, where people like to think about the One True vaccum state of the universe, while the term metastable originated in statistical physics, where regarding something as easily realisable a supercooled water as some kind of "false" phase of matter seemed unnatural (and I would also guess that the concept of metastability predates QFT).

Comment: @BySymmetry That's the impression I get too :) So there's no distinction between metastable vacua that can decay to a safe vacuum and those that just roll off to infinity?

Comment: I am not aware of a separate term for the two cases, no.